# Getting NullReference after Rebind in Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I am trying to replace a dependency when I am in the context of a specific method.

So I am doing something like this:

In my Ninject module I have the dependency originally registered like this:

```
Bind<IMyDependency>().To<OriginalType>();
```

Then in the method for which I want to replace the dependency I am using rebind, like this:

```
MyMethod()
{
   _kernel.Rebind<IMyDependency, ReplacementType>();  

   ... some logic ...

   _kernel.Rebind<IMyDependency, OriginalType>();      
}
```

However, after the first rebind I am getting NullReference when I try to resolve 'IMyDependency'

What am I missing? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to use

```
  _kernel.Rebind<IMyDependency, ReplacementType>();
```

instead of

```
  _kernel.Rebind<IMyDependency>().To(ReplacementType);
```

?

```
IBindingToSyntax<T1, T2> Rebind<T1, T2>();
```

method is used to rebind services T1 and T2, not to resolve T1 as T2.